# tcl: parse string into list

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm trying to parse a string into a flat list in TCL.

The string has the format of

```
name1='value1',name2='value2',name3='value3'
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to capture names and values into a list that looks like this:

```
{name1 value1 name2 value2 name3 value3}
```

Note that the name or value itself may contain anything which includes characters like `'` or `=` or `,`

Comment: How would you be sure that the string will be correctly parsed into the list?

Comment: By my above comment, I mean, how do you know which is the name and the value in a string such as: `name1,name1cont='name1cont',='value1',value1cont.='value1cont.'` where the name and values can contain any of `'`, `=` or `,`?

Comment: So `name1='value1',name2='value2',name3='value3'` has the key `name1` with value `value1',name2='value2',name3='value3`?

Comment: I was assuming the worst cases here. The name and the value cannot have `='` or `',` in them.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn no, each key should have its own value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, possible

```
set data {name1='value1',name2='value2',name3='value3'}
foreach {- key value -} [regexp -all -inline {(.*?)='(.*?)'(,|$)} $data] {
    lappend result $key $value
}
```

**Note**: If the key only occurs once, i suggest using dicts (`dict set result $key $value`).

Comment: Thanks man, it works. But I don't quite understand the `?` inside `(.*?)`.

Comment: Non-greedy. Don't try to match as much character as possible, otherwise you would get something like `name1='value1',name2='value2',name3=` as key and `'value3'` as value, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to replace the symbols `=`, `,` and `'` with spaces:

```
% set s {name1='value1',name2='value2',name3='value3'}
name1='value1',name2='value2',name3='value3'

% set new_s [string map {"='" " " "'," " " "'" " "} $s]
name1 value1 name2 value2 name3 value3
```

`string map` takes two parameters. The first is a list of old-new pairs of strings. The second is the string itself. Essentially, `string map` will search for the old strings and replace them with the new. For example, it will search for `='` and replaces with  (space).

## Update

The above solution assumes no space in the names or values. The following solution will work for those values with embedded spaces:

```
% set s {name1='value1',name2='value 2',name3='value3'}
name1='value1',name2='value2',name3='value3'

% string map {"=" " " "'" {"} "," " "} $s
name1 "value1" name2 "value 2" name3 "value3"
```

Comment: I guess you missed the notes that the key and value can also contain `'` `,` or `=`

Comment: It will break with input like `backslash='\'` or `{='curly'`.

Comment: Yes. I did miss that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a negative character class

```
set s {name1='value1',name2='value2',name3='value3'}
set result [regexp -inline -all -- {[^=',]+} $s]
```

Comment: No. this would fail if the name/value contains `=`, `'` or `,`